# Notice: Undefined offset: 5 when working with an array

Tags: php, ascii

I want to extract data from an ASC file. But when I try to extract data from it it tells me that it has an undefined offset?

This is the code that I use to extract the data (the error occurs at $data2, $data is fine):

```
        $File       = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $File2      = $_FILES['file2']['tmp_name'];
        $handle     = fopen($File, "r");
        $handle2    = fopen($File2, "r");
        $arrResult  = array();
        $arrResult2 = array();
        fgetcsv($handle);
        fgetcsv($handle);
        fgetcsv($handle);
        fgetcsv($handle);
        fgetcsv($handle);
        fgetcsv($handle);
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE && ($data2 = fgetcsv($handle2, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {



            //---------------------
            $artikelnmr       = $data[0];
            $barcode          = $data[1];
            $omschrijving_nl  = $data[2];
            $omschrijving_exp = $data[3];
            $bruto_prs        = $data[4];
            $staffel_prs      = $data[5];
            $aktie_prs        = $data[6];
            $bruto_antl       = $data[8];
            $staffel_antl     = $data[9];
            $aktie_aantal     = $data[10];
            $voorraad         = $data[15];
            $leverdatum       = $data[16];
            $besteld          = $data[17];
            $pallet_antl      = $data[19];
            $artikel_groep    = $data[22];
            $extra_info       = $data[27];


                //-----------------------
            $type             = $data2[0][0];
            $artikel          = $data2[0][1];
            $prijs1           = $data2[5];
            $prijs2           = $data2[6];
            $prijs3           = $data2[7];
            $prijs4           = $data2[8];
            $prijs5           = $data2[9];
                //----------------------
```

And this is the error that gets returned:

> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in C:\wamp64\www\jodeco\import.php
>   on line 53 Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

1   0.0011  414880  {main}( )   ...\import.php:0

2   0.0032  430384  importdb( ) ...\import.php:222

And this also happens for all the other data points (5 to 9)

Here are a few rows of the ASC file:

```
 0    1                                   2                    3  4   5        6        7        8        9             10     11
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 5    ;790148                              ;                    ;  ;   ;    4.35;    0.00;        ;        ;  0.00;      ;      ;
 1    ;790148                              ;                    ;  ;   ;    4.35;    0.00;        ;        ;  0.00;      ;      ;
```

Comment: Be carreful to the last line of your file when using `fgetcsv`. If this last line contents only carriage return, you will throw this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be like

```
 $artikelnmr = isset($data[0]) ? $data[0] : "";
```

Insted of

```
  $artikelnmr = $data[0];
```

You get undefined offset because `$data[5]` not found in your `$data` array
Try `isset()` to check offset is set or not.

Comment: I dont have any problems with $data. I have problems with $data2

Comment: Make `isset($data2[5]) ? $data2[5] : "";` try this.. etc...